# Add a character at the end of line in notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am using notepad++ and RegEx.

I have a SRT file and I want to add three question marks "???" whenever the first the three characters of a line are also three questions marks "???". However, I only wish to do this if the next line is blank. However, if the next line is not blank then I would like to add the ??? after the end of that next line.

For example this is that I have.

```
14
01:04:21,406 --> 01:04:24,887
??? Face I'd never see again

15
01:04:24,885 --> 01:04:27,638
??? It's a shame to awake
in a world of pain
```

Now I would like to add the ??? like this to both the lines.

```
14
01:04:21,406 --> 01:04:24,887
??? Face I'd never see again ???

15
01:04:24,885 --> 01:04:27,638
??? It's a shame to awake
in a world of pain ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ used to have problems with multiline matches, but the current releases are said to support Perl-style regexes much better. I don't have Notepad++ installed, but if its regex engine works correctly, then the following regex should solve your problem:

Search for `(?s)^(\?{3}.*?(?=\r?\n\r?\n|\z))` and replace with `\1???`.

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)         # Turn on dot-matches-all mode
^            # Match start of line
(            # Match and capture (group 1)
 \?{3}       # Three question marks
 .*?         # Any number of characters, as few as possible
 (?=         # until the following regex can be matched at the current position:
  \r?\n\r?\n #  Either two newlines in a row
 |           # or
  \z         #  the end of the file
 )           # End of lookahead assertion
)            # End of capturing group 1
```

Comment: Thanks that's a great help. After doing it I found out that there are instances where I don't want to add the ??? even if it started with one. And instead add it to the next line.

The distinguishing factor is that if a line starts with ??? and the next line is not blank, then I would like to add the ??? in the next line rather than the first line which started with ???

Any way of doing this?

Comment: @user1742965: Great to hear it. Welcome to StackOverflow, I hope you'll find it as much of a great resource as I do.